Use of MLA instruction at Optimization Level -Og in ARM GCC compiler
For the sample code below, I am using ARM GCC 10.2.1.
int myfunc(int num) {
int x,i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  x= (num*num)+i;
}
return x;}

}
When I use optimization level -O1 the following assembly code is generated:
myfunc:
    mov     r3, r0
    mul     r3, r0, r3
    add     r0, r3, #9
    bx      lr

When I use -Og the following assembly is generated:
myfunc:
    mov     r3, #0
    b       .L2
 L3:mla     r2, r0, r0, r3
    add     r3, r3, #1
 L2:cmp     r3, #9
    ble     .L3
    mov     r0, r2
    bx      lr

Can someone please tell me what flag causes the generation of MLA instruction when using -Og. Apparently -Og uses all flags used by -O1 except those which interfere with debugging. I have manually checked all O1 flags but can't reproduce the result generated by -Og. My goal is to identify specific flag that enables this instruction. Thanks

The -O* options in gcc are not just shorthand for some set of flags.  In some cases, they have functionality that does not correspond to any specific flag.
